# Make Python 3 recognize and understand grammar

Tags: python-3.3

I'm trying to create a python 3 program that will call you what you ask it to.

For example: `"Call me Steve"` should return `"Ok! I'll call you: Steve"` I don't want to use something like:

```
if user_input == "Steve":
   print output
```

I want it to *sense* the name from the command. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well I know you said you didn't want to use == comparator, but you could use

```
if 'Steve' in user_input:
```

Comment: @Lucio If you were working on a Siri equivalent (other virtual assistants are available ;D) you could save a whole list of baby names to a text file, then read them Into an array, and see if input is in the array?

Comment: I want the program to get the name from the input through the command "Call me"

Comment: If I were to use a list of baby names in a text file, how would I read them into an array?

Comment: There are many tutorials for reading and writing to files, just search file read and write in python on google!

Comment: A prompt for the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex match to get the name as follows:

```
import re
m = re.search("Call me (\S+)", "Call me Steve")
name = m.group(1)
return "Ok! I'll call you: " + name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "sense", but all chatbots (I am aware of) are built using  more or less complex pattern matching and a database with canned answers, possibly with some context- and semantically-related state to be able to follow a "topic".

I think [ELIZA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) is one of the older examples. It includes some of the input in some of the answers and it can perhaps convince someone for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file into an array, I would do it as follows.

```
    names = []
    with open('names.txt') as file:
        for word in file:
            names.append(word)
```

and then later on in your program:

```
    if user_input in names:
        name  = user_input
        print('I' call you: ',Name)
```

(sorry I couldn't test this code myself)